# Error: "missing 5 required positional arguments" In Python, Tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

The specific error is:

_getandcreate() missing 5 required positional arguments: '_get_userpass', '_createuser', 't', 'username', and 'password'

Problematic subroutine:

```
def create_regwindow(self):
    t = tk.Toplevel(self)
    t.wm_title("Register")
    t.entry_user = tk.Entry(t)
    t.entry_pass = tk.Entry(t, show="*")
    t.title = tk.Label(t, text="Enter your new username and password below")
    t.field_user = tk.Label(t, text="Username")
    t.field_pass = tk.Label(t, text="Password")
    t.regbutton = tk.Button(t, text="Create Account", command=self._getandcreate) <-- HERE
    t.title.grid(row=0, sticky=tk.E)
    t.title.grid(row=0, column=1)
    t.field_user.grid(row=1, sticky=tk.E)
    t.field_pass.grid(row=2, sticky=tk.E)
    t.entry_user.grid(row=1, column=1)
    t.entry_pass.grid(row=2, column=1)
    t.regbutton.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

And the actual subroutine here:

```
def _getandcreate(self, _get_userpass, _createuser, t, username, password):
    _get_userpass(t)
    _createuser(username, password)
```

I need them variables to be passed into the command in the first block of code (labelled HERE), however, when I do this, I need to put these variables into a part of my code higher up (within **init**, whole code at bottom) - causing the issue of them not being defined.

I'm slightly confused. The purpose is, when the user clicks "Create Account", the data the user entered is taken and added to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback system cannot know all your arguments. You could wrap your call in a `lambda`

```
t.regbutton = tk.Button(t, text="Create Account", command=self._getandcreate)
```

would become

```
t.regbutton = tk.Button(t, text="Create Account", command=lambda : self._getandcreate(t,<needed args>))
```

But there's much better to do here since you only deal with object members (methods or data).

Declare the `_getandcreate` and `_get_userpass` methods like this:

```
def _getandcreate(self):
    username, password = self._get_userpass()
    self._createuser(username, password)

def _get_userpass(self):
    t = self.__toplevel
    username = t.entry_user.get()
    password = t.entry_pass.get()
    return username, password
```

and set `self.__toplevel` in `create_regwindow`:

```
def create_regwindow(self):
    t = tk.Toplevel(self)
    self.__toplevel = t
```

Comment: see my answer: you have to change `get_userpass` too. remove `t` parameter.